# different Style in last Character to show required field

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

Need to style red for * to show that its required field (in label)

```
            <TextInput
              mode="flat"
              ref={formFilledByRef}
              label={"Form filled by*"}
              style={styles.inputField}
              returnKeyType={'send'}
              value={state.form_filled_by.value}
              error={state.form_filled_by.error !== undefined}
              onSubmitEditing={}

              onChange={e => {
                handleOnChange()
            />
```